# Matching last occurrence in js regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having a hard time figuring out a solution for my problem:

I have this regex:

```
(?:\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s(?:01|02|03|04|05|06|07|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26+).*?(02521)\s(?:[\d.,]+)
```

And I'm using it for catching the number 02521 (I want to know how many occurrences of 02521 exist) so, the regex below finds a date and afterwards, finds one of these numbers:

```
01|02|03|04|05|06|07|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26
```

Catch everything between until the 02521 number.

And it is working as you can see [here](http://regexr.com/3cnhc)

But I want to make it more secure, and the date is a problem, because I want to find the last date before the number, more or less like [this](http://regexr.com/3cnhf)

But I can't, because this last regex finds just one occurrence. So I would like to mix both, is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: How does your test case reflect that "it is working"? I only see the regex, and RegExr's default test text. There are not matches.

Comment: Also, are you sure about the digit range? The last one is `26+` which would match 26 but also 266 or 2666666.

Comment: good point Bram Vanroy, i didn't catch this problem.

Comment: i need find the last date before my goal number, after one space, after the digit range, and after that i can have nothing or i can have other not specific things, and after my goal number.

Comment: my problem is before my goal number, i could have more numbers or nothing, like this: http://regexr.com/3cnhf, i have two 02521.

Comment: i mean.. more numbers, words, anything..

Comment: i was able to improve http://regexr.com/3cnhr, but i'm afraid to miss something.

Comment: @FátimaAlves, you want to get the last occurrence of '02521' OR number of occurrences of '02521' ?

Comment: i want catch the number of 02521 occurrences, but i have so much variables to think, see this case: http://regexr.com/3cni4 the last is being ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that your text may have fragments that can not be covered with your initial regexp pattern.
 Those are `18/07/2011 I1 04101`, `12/07/2011 I1 02410 9.501,60`, `15/07/2011 I1 02522 280,93` and some others. 
 As you can see, there can be alpha-numeric sequence (two characters/digits) between date range and the needed number.
So change your pattern as will be shown below:
*For demonstration, I will output just some part your last text(the whole text is quite big). This part contains 4 matches of `02410` number.*

```
var text = "AUGUSTO PERES FILHO 180.87386.99-5 23/10/2006 01 02410 6.488,00 0,00 0,00 406,09 0,00 0,00 ANTONIO CARLOS BAGNATORI FERNANDES 124.79898.68-9 19/08/2008 01 02522 4.730,15 0,00 0,00 406,09 0,00 0,00 ANTONIO VALDECIR ROSSI 106.37070.87-6 03/01/2005 01 04101 7.003,00 3.450,50 0,00 406,09 0,00 0,00 ANUBIA MARIA DE OLIVEIRA RODRIGUES 123.88469.32-7 03/11/2010 01 03548 3.078,53 0,00 0,00 338,63 0,00 0,00 ARAI DE OLIVEIRA RODRIGUES 207.26620.55-0 28/11/2006 01 03548 2.331,09 0,00 0,00 256,41 0,00 0,00 ARIANE ANGELO DA SILVA 135.67665.77-3 09/02/2011 01 04223 1.349,00 0,00 0,00 121,41 0,00 0,00 AUDREY DOS SANTOS 200.30943.45-5 21/12/2009 01 04110 1.935,00 0,00 0,00 212,85 0,00 0,00 BARBARA CRISTINA PEREIRA ASSUNCAO MAIORI 132.48719.81-7 03/05/2010 01 02524 2.255,91 0,00 0,00 248,15 0,00 0,00 BIANCA DA COSTA SANTOS 207.86622.17-7 01/12/2010 01 04110 1.636,68 0,00 0,00 147,30 0,00 0,00 BRUNA ALINE MORIBE 132.04120.89-8 16/02/2009 01 02410 3.421,00 0,00 0,00 376,31 0,00 0,00 BRUNA D ANDREA 133.71271.77-2 08/05/2008 01 04110 1.870,00 0,00 0,00 205,70 0,00 0,00 ,MINISTÉRIO DO TRABALHO E EMPREGO - MTE MINISTÉRIO DA FAZENDA - MF DATA: 22/01/2016 GFIP - SEFIP 8.40 (22/03/2012) TABELAS 31.0 (25/01/2012) HORA: 18:42:37 PÁG : 0004/0034 RELAÇÃO DOS TRABALHADORES CONSTANTES NO ARQUIVO SEFIP MODALIDADE : 9-CONFIRMAÇÃO INFORMAÇÕES ANTERIORES - REC/DECL AO FGTS E DECL À PREVIDÊNCIA EMPRESA: CVC BRASIL OPERADORA E AGENCIA DE VIAGEN INSCRIÇÃO: 10.760.260/0001-19 COMP: 07/2011 COD REC:115 COD GPS: 2100 FPAS: 515 OUTRAS ENT: 0115 SIMPLES: 1 RAT: 1.0 FAP: 0.50 RAT AJUSTADO: 0.50 TOMADOR/OBRA: INSCRIÇÃO: NOME TRABALHADOR PIS/PASEP/CI ADMISSÃO CAT OCOR DATA/COD MOVIMENTAÇÃO CBO REM SEM 13º SAL REM 13ºSAL BASE CÁL 13ºSAL PREV SOC CONTRIB SEG DEVIDA DEPÓSITO JAM BASE CÁL PREV SOCIAL BRUNA MARQUES 133.08610.89-1 01/09/2010 01 01/07/2011 J 04110 410,79 619,46 619,46 82,41 0,00 0,00 BRUNO ALTINO SANTANA DOS SANTOS 161.17769.57-2 03/02/2011 01 04223 1.412,26 0,00 0,00 127,10 0,00 0,00 BRUNO ROSOLEM DOS SANTOS 131.85360.89-2 01/04/2008 01 02410 2.140,00 12/07/2011 I1 02410 9.501,60";

var matches = text.match(/\s(?:\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})(?:[\d\s\w.,]+)?\s(02410)\s(?:[\d.,]+)/gim);
console.log(matches.length);
// the output: 4
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jfqf4vb5/

And here is a real example with your initial text:
http://regexr.com/3cnia

Answer (score 0):

An approach consists to separate each records (it's easy since they are separated by a space and each starts with a date followed by a space, a number (00-26) and a space:

```
var results = data
    .split(/ (?=[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4} (?:[01][0-9]|2[0-6]) )/)
    .filter(function (record) {
        return record.indexOf(' 02521 ', 13) > 0;
    }); // index after the 00-26 number--^

console.log(results)
```

Then you can do what you want with selected records.